# Matching a string that's arbitrarily splits over multiple lines

Tags: python, regex, multiline

Is there a way in regex's to match a string that is arbitrarily split over multiple lines - say we have the following format in a file:

```
msgid "This is "
"an example string"
msgstr "..."

msgid "This is an example string"
msgstr "..."

msgid ""
"This is an " 
"example" 
" string"
msgstr "..."

msgid "This is " 
"an unmatching string" 
msgstr "..."
```

So we would like to have a pattern that would match all the example strings, ie: match the string regardless of how it's split across lines. Notice that we are after a specific string as shown in the sample, not just any string. So in this case we would like to match the string `"This is an example string"`.

Of course we can can easily concat the strings then apply the match, but got me wondering if this is possible. I'm talking **Python** regex's but a general answer is ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want to match a series of words? If so, you could look for words with just spaces (\s) in between, since \s matches newlines and spaces alike.

```
import re

search_for = "This is an example string"
search_for_re = r"\b" + r"\s+".join(search_for.split()) + r"\b"
pattern = re.compile(search_for_re)
match = lambda s: pattern.match(s) is not None

s = "This is an example string"
print match(s), ":", repr(s)

s = "This is an \n example string"
print match(s), ":", repr(s)

s = "This is \n an unmatching string"
print match(s), ":", repr(s)
```

Prints:

```
True : 'This is an example string'
True : 'This is an \n example string'
False : 'This is \n an unmatching string'
```

Comment: Yes the question didn't specify if splitting is on word boundaries or char boundaries. But a similar concept would apply for both.

Comment: This approach is very clever, but I can see one issue with it: if the string contains meta characters, that would wreck havoc with our pattern. I'm not sure how that can be handled.

Comment: That's why I asked if you intend to search a series of normal words. If you want to search for more complex structures you'll have to form the regex differently.. but the answer to the question clearly is: "use \s". How to handle arbitrary input as search pattern is a completely different question. You could simply allow meta characters, or escape them, or alert the user not to use them etc.

Comment: You could use this for example on any single word to ensure it is matched literally:
http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.escape

Comment: Thx, I accept your answer is correct to the parameters of the Q. I'm just thinking that the approach of dynamically structuring the pattern is probably complicating things a bit, and it's better to avoid using regex's for this specific case. regards.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky with the need for quotes on every line, and the allowance of empty lines. Here's a regex that matches the file you posted correctly:

```
'(""\n)*"This(( "\n(""\n)*")|("\n(""\n)*" )| )is(( "\n(""\n)*")|("\n(""\n)*" )| )an(( "\n(""\n)*")|("\n(""\n)*" )| )example(( "\n(""\n)*")|("\n(""\n)*" )| )string"'
```

That's a bit confusing, but all it is is the string you want to match, but it starts with:

```
(""\n)*"
```

and has replaces the spaces between each word with:

```
(( "\n(""\n)*")|("\n(""\n)*" )| )
```

which checks for three different possibilities after each word, either a "space, quote, newline, (unlimited number of empty strings) quote", or that same sequence but more the space to the end, or just a space.

A much easier way to get this working would be to write a little function that would take in the string you are trying to match and return the regex that will match it:

```
def getregex(string):
    return '(""\n)*"' + string.replace(" ", '(( "\n(""\n)*")|("\n(""\n)*" )| )') + '"'
```

So, if you had the file you posted in a string called "filestring", you would get the matches like this:

```
import re

def getregex(string):
    return '(""\n)*"' + string.replace(" ", '(( "\n(""\n)*")|("\n(""\n)*" )| )') + '"'

matcher = re.compile(getregex("This is an example string"))

for i in matcher.finditer(filestring):
    print i.group(0), "\n"

>>> "This is "
    "an example string"

    "This is an example string"

    ""
    "This is an "
    "example"
    " string"
```

This regex doesn't take into account the space you have after "example" in the third msgid, but I assume this is generated by a machine and that's a mistake.